# Assign a column value from a list of values in a loop in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am certain that someone else has had to do something similar, but I am having a hard time finding an example of what I need.

I have an array that is likely to change over time. I am trying to use that array to distribute my portfolio of account evenly between my teams.  I cannot directly alter the SQL database, so I have to extract and re-upload through XML to accomplish this.

Here is the psuedocode (forgive me for writing weird psuedo):

```
    Declare @Collector as array
    Declare @LoopedValue as varchar (60)
    set    @Collector [Team1, Team2, Team3]

    Set @LoopedValue to index 0 of array

    For each row returned    

    SELECT

    '<LOAN UpdateFlag= "1" LoanNumber= "'+la.loan_number+'" CollectionOfficerNumber= "'+@LoopedValue+'"> </LOAN>'

    FROM loanacct la

    where
    la.portfolio_code_id = 1
    AND status_code_no = 0
    AND la.acctrefno not IN (SELECT las.acctrefno from loanacct_statuses AS las where las.status_code_no IN  (11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 19, 20, 22, 26, 28, 35, 36, 38, 39, 62)
        )
        --Excludes accounts with Status Codes 11=Repossessed; 12=Pending Repo; 13=Bankruptcy Ch 7; 14=Charge-off; 17=Unsecured bad debt; 19=Clear to sell; 20=Bankruptcy Ch. 13; 22=Repo Sold; 26:Voluntary repossession; 28=Move to inventory; 35=Deficiency; 36=Unsecured Balance; 38=Discharged Ch 7 BK; 39=Discharged Ch13 BK: 62=Pre-Bankruptcy

Set @LoopedValue  to @LoopedValue+1. 
If @LoopedValue > 2 set @LoopedValue to 0 Else end
end

    ORDER by la.days_past_due desc
```

The question I have is what on earth would I put into the @LoopedValue section to achieve a Column 1 = Team1, Column 2 = Team2, Column3 = Team3, Column4 = Team1 etc result?

I actually do not want to assign a random value among the Teams, as this may create an imbalance of account difficulty.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I can assure you that you do NOT want to use a loop for this. However it is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I think you could use row_number() on a select and derive an index by using modulus of the row number by number of teams. This would generate a cycle of indexes 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 etc for three teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested code per my comment, using ROW_NUMBER() and modulus to create a cycling index into the teams.

```
-- Given table of loans =================================
    CREATE TABLE #Loan ( 
        Loan_Number int
        , Loan_Name varchar(30) 
        , Days_Past_Due int
        );

    INSERT INTO #Loan VALUES
        (23, 'First loan', 23),
        (34, 'alksdjfl', 12 ),
        (123, 'aswerjlj', 17 ),
        (324, 'asdasdf', 52 ),
        (8126, 'slaksjdrjlj', 80 ),
        (323, 'asdfasldfkj', 123 ),
        (224, 'alsdfal', 4 ),
        (2342, 'asldkfasldkj', 5 ),
        (451, 'asdlfjkasldjf', 67 )
        ;
-- =======================================================

-- Create and load a table with teams indexed starting at 1
Create Table #Team (TeamIX int, Team_Name varchar(50))
Insert into #Team 
    SELECT ROW_Number() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL) )  TeamIX
            , Team_Name from ( VALUES ( 'Team1' ), ('Team2'), ('Team3' ) ) TT(Team_Name) ;

-- Get the number of teams to use as the modulus divisor
DECLARE @TeamMax int; 
SELECT @TeamMax = COUNT(*) FROM #Team;


-- Create a temp table #FORXML of loans joined with teams by
-- allocating loan to team using modulus of row number
SELECT
 L.Loan_Number
 , L.TeamIX 
 , L.Loan_Name
 , T.Team_Name
 , L.Days_Past_Due
 INTO #FORXML
    FROM ( 
            SELECT ( 
                        -- TeamIX provides a cycling set of team numbers 1,2,3 etc up to the max team number
                        ROW_Number() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT Days_Past_Due ) DESC ) - 1 ) % @TeamMax + 1 TeamIX
                    , Loan_Number
                    , Loan_Name 
                    , Days_Past_Due
            FROM #LOAN 
        ) L
    JOIN #Team T
        ON T.TeamIX = L.TeamIX
    ;

-- Declare the xml variable to receive the generated XML
DECLARE @XML XML;

-- Generate the XML from the #FORXML table
SET @XML = '<LOANS>' + (
        SELECT Loan_Number [@LoanNumber]
                , TeamIX [@CollectionOfficerNumber] 
                , Loan_Name [@LoanName]
                , Team_Name [@TeamName]
                , Days_Past_Due [@DaysPastDue]
                FROM #FORXML FOR XML PATH ('LOAN') 
        ) + '</LOANS>';

    -- Report the XML for testing
    SELECT @XML XML;

-- CLEAN UP TEMP TABLES
Drop Table #Team;
Drop Table #Loan;
Drop Table #FORXML;
```

Which code gives the following result:

```
<LOANS>
  <LOAN LoanNumber="323" CollectionOfficerNumber="1" LoanName="asdfasldfkj" TeamName="Team1" DaysPastDue="123" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="8126" CollectionOfficerNumber="2" LoanName="slaksjdrjlj" TeamName="Team2" DaysPastDue="80" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="451" CollectionOfficerNumber="3" LoanName="asdlfjkasldjf" TeamName="Team3" DaysPastDue="67" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="324" CollectionOfficerNumber="1" LoanName="asdasdf" TeamName="Team1" DaysPastDue="52" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="23" CollectionOfficerNumber="2" LoanName="First loan" TeamName="Team2" DaysPastDue="23" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="123" CollectionOfficerNumber="3" LoanName="aswerjlj" TeamName="Team3" DaysPastDue="17" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="34" CollectionOfficerNumber="1" LoanName="alksdjfl" TeamName="Team1" DaysPastDue="12" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="2342" CollectionOfficerNumber="2" LoanName="asldkfasldkj" TeamName="Team2" DaysPastDue="5" />
  <LOAN LoanNumber="224" CollectionOfficerNumber="3" LoanName="alsdfal" TeamName="Team3" DaysPastDue="4" />
</LOANS>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on how to do a post correctly. I honestly needed that. (I'll try and clean this post up a bit to make it more clear). That said, your solution is REALLY close to what I need. My only question is how would I populate the #Loan table with queried results?

Comment: Sorry, that last question was dumb. Your answer is the right way to do it. But I did have to tweak it a bit since I am unable to  drop tables in this database (lame, I know). That said, the modulus method was EXACTLY what I needed. I'll try and tweak the post so it looks better and contains my final answer. Thanks for the help!